# How to pass parameter in .js.erb render file and get

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I am developing `rails 4 application` where i have to render `.js.erb file` from controller.

Now i have to pass parameter from controller to .js.erb file and use that parameter to that file.

Controller:

```
  if @user.user_settings == nil
      render "save_account_settings.js.erb", :locals => {:msg => "Your account settings saved successfully"}
  else
      render "save_account_settings.js.erb", :locals => {:msg => "Something goes wrong. Please try again."}
  end
```

Above code from controller and I have to pass parameter to .js.erb file and use it.

```
File:  save_account_settings.js.erb

$('#saved_message').text('<%=params[:msg]%>');
```

But not working for me.

Where is i wrong. Need to change file name or something else.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your message as an instance variable exactly as you would in a .html.erb view:

```
if @user.user_settings == nil
  @msg = "Your account settings saved successfully"
else
  @msg = "Something goes wrong. Please try again."
end

render "save_account_settings"
```

And in your js.erb view:

```
$('#saved_message').text('<%= @msg %>');
```

Note: `params` in the controller *and* the view will always be the parameters of the request. When you use `:locals` to pass variables to a view for rendering, they will be available as local variables in the view i.e. just `msg` not `params[:msg]`. The latter would be trying to get the msg parameter from the request i.e. `?msg=value-from-query`